# HTML5 Audio - Same music for all webpages

Tags: javascript, html, audio

I am trying to stream the same audio file in the background using HTML5.

Currently, the mp3 file plays right from the beginning when a new webpage is loaded.

However, I need the audio file to pause when a user navigates to a new webpage and then continue playing from the last paused position.

How can I approach solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store `element.currentTime` in something like `sessionStorage`. Then on the next page, get the `sessionStorage` value, and set the `element.currentTime` to that value.

[Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_audio_and_video_in_Firefox#Seeking_through_media)

[W3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#dom-media-currenttime)